# PrintHelper multiple prints

Tags: android-print-framework

I am using the PrintHelper class to print an image. It is working good. But can anyone please help me in how to initiate multiple image prints at a time ?

Following is the code I am using for printing each image

```
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
                    photoPrinter.printBitmap("printName", bitmap);
```

Thank you.